# Can't remove range of options inside multiple select tags

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using jQuery and I have a group of select elements saved to servoSelects.  Some of them have class "lgServo" and some don't.  Of the ones that have that class, I want to remove all the options between index 0 and ~variable~.  I don't understand how to do this.

```
servoSelects.filter('.lgServo').find('option:gt(0)').remove('lt:variable');
```

This line of code doesn't work but is it close to what I want?

Comment: Please update your question with a **runnable** [mcve] demonstrating the problem using Stack Snippets (the `<>` toolbar button). This both helps people understand your question better, and helps them demonstrate their answers solve the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I don't understand how to do this.

String concatenation:

```
servoSelects.filter('.lgServo').find('option:gt(0):lt(' + variable = ')');
// --------------------------------------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

or possibly [`slice`](http://api.jquery.com/slice/):

```
servoSelects.filter('.lgServo').find('option').slice(0, variable).remove();
```

Comment: I've heard slice() has much better efficiency than gt():lt().  Your 2nd example looks nice but it only works on the first select element and not on the 2nd select element.  How could I make it work on all select elements?

Comment: @user1592980: If there are multiple selects, you'll want the first version or you'll need to do an `each` loop on the selects doing the `.find('option').slice(...)`.

Comment: An excellent solution.  Thank you so much for your time, T.J. Crowder.